# Exclude account from twitter search results

Tags: twitter, twitter-search

I'd like to search for everything relating to these terms:

`sidigital OR sidgtl OR sidigital.co`

[Example search](https://twitter.com/search?f=realtime&q=sidigital%20OR%20sidgtl%20OR%20sidigital.co&src=savs)

but I don't want to see anything from the specific user `@sidgtl` how do I do this? I can't ignore `sidigital` because I still want to see people mentioning the account, just nothing from the account itself.

Thank you!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You use `-from:username` to exclude tweets from a user.

So for your example:

`sidigital OR sidgtl OR sidigital.co -from:sidgtl`

Comment: is there a twitter page or something that says that please? Edit: ah never mind got it. i think you can even do just -username

Answer (score 0):

Try building your query here:
https://twitter.com/search-advanced

Once you've entered what you need, copy the URL in the address bar.

You may also find it useful to refer to the search API documentation here:
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets

Comment: Thanks I've check out both before but neither seem to provide answers to excluding a specific account from results