# Is there any way to exclude any accounts mentioning specific terms from twitter search results

Tags: twitter, twitter-search

I'm trying to build some advanced twitter searches to monitor certain items.
At present, they get thrown off by people using one of the keywords in the username.

I can't just mute / block all those users, as some of them are ones I follow.

At the moment, the only way I can see to completely exclude an account from results is:

```
    -(@username) -from:username
```

This works, but the approach rapidly gets lengthy if there are quite a few names to exclude.
It also doesn't allow me to exclude all accounts containing username - i.e. @username1 @username2

One thought would be to create a list of accounts to exclude and then filter the list. That doesn't seem to work though as it won't help in excluding replies to these people.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude account from twitter search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823700/exclude-account-from-twitter-search-results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was confronting a similar problem and the way I ended up solving it is exactly as you suggested with a tiny addition:

Like you, I created a list for accounts with usernames similar to my keywords, then used the `list:` operator with my list's ID, in minus `-` to exclude tweets from the list members.

I also ended up getting lots of replies to accounts on my list, so i used the `exclude:replies` operator and it worked quite good.

`[keyword(s)] -list:[list_id] exclude:replies`

The only false positives I kept on getting were tweets which quoted members of my list but adding `exclude:quote` did more damage than help as it filtered also legitimate tweets with benign quotes.